# Games for which the Lemke-Howson algorithm provides incomplete results

Tags: computational-complexity, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I am exploring a large number of 2-player games. The Lemke-Howson algorithm is computationally very reasonable, and is able to find many equilibria. On the other hand, I know that there are equilibria such that the algorithm cannot find in principle.

I was wondering if there was any way, upon inspection of the payoff matrices, to find out whether the game in question is one for which L-H will give incomplete results, so that I could then try more computationally intensive algorithms on those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be an open problem. The closest remark that I could find is by [Shapley in 1981](http://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/notes/2009/N1736.pdf). I haven't found much thereafter, but, of course, I could have overlooked something. (Naturally, I am excluding the trivial "inspection" of using a computationally less reasonable algorithm first, and see whether they differ in their solutions.)

> [image]

Related: [Gilboa and Zemel (1989)](http://www.tau.ac.il/~igilboa/pdf/Gilboa_Zemel_Nash_Complexity.pdf). I know next to nothing about (average) complexity, but perhaps somebody else can comment on whether this means you're in bad luck.

Comment: Yes, I know that paper, and had overlooked that comment. That's helpful, thanks. I will wait a couple of days, in case some more recent literature might surface, and accept your answer otherwise.